# Is this website only for the cream of the crop?

Tags: support, specific-question

I pretty much started learning Mathematics and I have no clue how TEX works as well. So it is already challenging to learn both at the same time. Also I posted some really easy questions on Complex inequalities, as how to graph them. Some ELITE people here put it on HOLD. May be it was not in MathJAX format or maybe it was too easy for Einsteins here I dunno. I think it takes time to learn how to post it correctly in MathJAX and i am willing to learn that. But why make it into a exclusive community? I searched the Tags  Graphing Complex inequalities and guess what almost nothing, some answers are also very short and specific to that problem. If you want to be open and accept new people here. Please realise that it's not for Exclusive difficult problems only!

Comment: In order to avoid being a homework-factory, the site enforces a rule that requires it's users to write down the context and their efforts (explain where you are stuck). I found some of your questions lacking in this regard. One more thing: you are not a dumb guy (avoid writing such things in your posts or else dumb people will down-vote you.)

Comment: You are absolutely right. This site promotes elitism. Disguised with the absurd rule that requires (when convenient, because questions that look appealing to the elite get overlooked) writing down context and effort a lot of perfectly nice questions get closed. Just don't get worked out when a question gets closed. You can still get complete answers in the comment section, and you will, if you question has an answer.

Comment: Even mover funny is that sometimes the question can be a tough/tricky question worthy of the elite, but a handful of the first viewer fail to think a little on the question and vote to close. I have seen professors from universities falling into that behavior. And it is funny because the question get closed out of the ignorance of the closers. There are a lot of things wrong with that rule of "show effort" and "show context", so don't worry about it. You are not at fault.

Comment: It is very simple really. If you do not want downvotes then do not write bad questions.

Comment: You won't make any friends here, Sherlock, with sarcasm. There's no need for ELITE or for reference to "Einsteins". You could make the same points, in a civilized way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be intended as a rant, rather than a question.

Comment: If you write down your reasoning and where exactly you get stuck, very few people will downvote it. If you just post a question straight from your homework set, we feel like you just want someone else to do your homework for you. We want to help clarify the details you have issues with, not do your homework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm sorry, but when your "question" is "[Factor: $z^5 - i = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1009166/1)", you shouldn't really expect to get a treatise on factoring methods in return — and this is independent of the "difficulty" of the question.  Actually, what you received is a lot more than what you should have, IMHO. Please realise that this isn't (supposed to be) a place for you to get your homework solved for free! [Put some more effort into asking your questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and see what comes out of it.

Comment: ok i think you' re example made me realise what my problem was. The question was short and i should have put my way of solving there too?

Comment: how about letting me start from all over again and edit the question to show what i really should have done?

Comment: @SherlockHomies: You have the ability to edit your questions. Actually, when your questions are put on-hold (for reasons other than being a duplicate), that what _you're supposed to do_. After an edit, your question would then be placed in a "re-open queue" where users with [sufficient privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) vote on whether it should be re-opened (taken off-hold).

Comment: yes i understood that now. I already have gotten the answer from the post. I just wanted to edit the post so that someone else might make use of it. I will not make the same mistakes now. :)

Comment: @Sherlock: Ask questions whose answer is something you want to learn. If you want to learn about adding decimal numbers, for example, "What is 19 + 23?" is a very bad question; the only good answer is "42" which is not what you want to hear and isn't useful to anybody. Some people will try to guess what question you really mean to ask or take an opportunity to stand on their favorite soapbox, but really the only reliable way to get the answer you want is to ask for it. (it also helps distinguish you from all the people who are only seeking to crowdsource their work)

Comment: @Hurkyl: Those were meticulously chosen numbers, weren't they? :-)